# Is it possible to use MapView with FragmentManager and ListFragment

Tags: android

My app is using a ListFragment on left side  that the user can use to select what fragment to use on the right hand side.

In sort it seems impossible to show the MapView more than once. The first problem is that it only allow one instance of MapView per Activity.

```
# Exception 1:
You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
```

Therefore, I saved my MapView and container in the Activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   mapViewContainer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.maplayout, null);
   mapView = (MapView) mapViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.map_view); 
}
```

However, this give me the next problem:

```
# Exception 2:
The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child’s parent first.
```

I have tried to remove the view, using this code:

```
((ViewGroup)mapViewContainer).removeView(mapView);
((ViewGroup)mapView.getParent()).removeView(mapView);
```

Got a NullPointerExeption.

I would appreciate any good ideas, or if you could share if you have been successful in doing this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, bumped into this one, too.

Do not add your MapView in XML layout file for your fragment. Instead, just leave a place for it, say, in a LinearLayout with id="@+id/your_map_container_id"

Declare a MapView private member in YourMapContainerFragment's:

```
public class YourMapContainerFragment extends Fragment {
    private MapView mMapView;
    //...
```

Then, go like this in YourMapContainerFragment's onCreateView():

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... Inflate your fragment's layout...
    // ...
    if (mMapView == null) {
        mMapView = new MapView(getActivity(), /*String*/YOUR_MAPS_API_KEY);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup)mMapView.getParent()).removeView(mMapView);
    }
    ViewGroup mapContainer = (ViewGroup) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.your_map_container_id);
    mapContainer.addView(mMapView);
    // ...
}
```

This will make the same MapView object be reused across removals/additions of your fragment to activity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if works for me too in a couple of day. I'm really grateful.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've spent the previous 3-4 hours of my all-nighter on this one!
I realized what was going on, but was failing as I tried to keep the same MapView for multiple uses.
I wish I could give you a second +1, haha.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, if I add a button on the map with a relativeLayout, why the button is not showing? Please help.

Comment: Well, that really depends on how you do it. Also, does the button show when you're not using the reattachment technique from the answer?